# angular jasmine multiple nested httpbackend calls

Tags: angularjs, http, jasmine, angular-promise, httpbackend

I am trying to test a angularjs service with jasmine that calls a resource service and in the then function calls another nested resource function. I am using httpbackend to flush mock responses. The issue is that, while testing, it is not flushing the second response to the second nested resource service request and I am erred out with the error *Error: Unflushed requests: 1*

**RestaurantService**

```
var deferred;
var restaurantinfo = {};

var loadMenu = function(){
    return Menu.query({}).$promise.then(function(response){
        restaurantinfo.menu = response
    })
}

var loadLocation = function(){
    return Location.query({}).$promise.then(function(response){
        restaurantinfo.location = response;
    })
}

var getRestaurantInfo = function(){
    if(!deferred && (!restaurantinfo.menu.length == 0 || restaurantinfo.location.length === 0)){
        deferred = $q.defer();
            return loadMenu()
               .then(loadLocations)
               .then(function(){
                    deferred.resolve(billinghistory);
                    return deferred.promise;
                })
        } else {
            if(!deferred.promise.$$state.status){ return deferred.promise; }
            deferred.resolve(billinghistory);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
}
```

**Test Spec**

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, RestaurantService, _Menu_, _Locations_){
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    mockRestaurantService = _RestaurantService_;


    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/api/menu').respond(mockMenu);
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/api/locations').respond(mockLocations);

    mockBalanceService.getRestaurantInfo();
    httpBackend.flush()

}))

afterEach(function(){
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
})
```

the loadMenu and loadLocation functions just call angular Resource services

httpbackend is flushing the first call to *api/menu* but is not making the second call to *api/location*

Comment: please can you put the angualr code of the promises in detail.

Comment: Updated as much as I can, the software I work on is pretty proprietary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out I was only flushing one of the backend calls. I added another *httpBackend.flush()* and both backend calls were flushed.

Answer (score 0):

th property : 'returnValue' to mock the http service, and make a spyOn to the call

```
var error = {
                code : 500,
                mensaje1:'err'
            },

                spyOn(getRestaurantInfo)
                .and.returnValue({
                    then: function (callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
                        callbackError(error);
                    }
                });
```

This will be a promise for error.
Tell me if well for your code.
thanks